# Faye with nodejs over HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, faye

I'm trying to setup my production server to use faye messages using nodejs and HTTPS, but no luck.

What I have until now is:

**A faye + nodejs server setup file:**

```
var https = require('https');
var faye = require('faye');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/httpd/ssl/example.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/httpd/ssl/example.com.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/httpd/ssl/ca_bundle.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options);
var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye', timeout: 60});

bayeux.attach(server);
server.listen(8000);
```

**A rails helper to send messages:**

```
def broadcast(channel, &block)
  message = {:channel => channel, :data => capture(&block)}
  uri = URI.parse(Rails.configuration.faye_url)
  Net::HTTPS.post(uri, message.to_json)
end
```

**A javascript function to open a listener:**

```
function openListener(channel, callback){
    var faye_client = new Faye.Client("<%= Rails.configuration.faye_url %>");
    faye_client.subscribe(channel , callback);
    return faye_client;
}
```

**My faye url config in production.rb:**

```
config.faye_url = "https://example.com:8000/faye"
```

**And finally, a call in my page javascript:**

```
fayeClient = openListener("my_channel" , function(data) {
    //do something...
});
```

Everything was working when testing over http on development machine. But in production don't.

If I point browser to https://example.com:8000/faye.js I got the correct javascript file.

What could be happen?

Comment: Is your cert self signed? I don't know about the Ruby APIs but in most APIs while you make an HTTPS post there is option to *not* to verify the HTTPS cert as the cert is self signed.

Comment: Yes, it is. I got from Godaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with Apache server.

I had switch to nginx and now it´s working.

However, I need to make some configurations:

**Faye + node.js setup file:**

```
var http = require('http'),
    faye = require('faye');

var server = http.createServer(),
    bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye', timeout: 60});

bayeux.attach(server);
server.listen(8000);
```

**Rails helper:**

```
def broadcast(channel, &block)
  message = {:channel => channel, :data => capture(&block)}
  uri = URI.parse(Rails.configuration.faye_url)
  Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
end
```

**Faye url:**

```
https://example.com/faye
```

**And finally, nginx config**

```
server {
    # Listen on 80 and 443
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /home/rails/myapp/public;

    ssl_certificate /home/rails/ssl/myapp.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/rails/ssl/myapp.key;

    # Redirect all non-SSL traffic to SSL.
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location /faye {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Short words: nginx convert https requests in /faye address, to http in port 8000.
Use default http in server side, and https in client side.